# Stuck with eslint Error Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, ecmascript-5

Error: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.

I have this code snippet but I can't remove this lint error

```
  for (const key of keys1) {
    const val1 = object1[key];
    const val2 = object2[key];
    const areObjects = isObject(val1) && isObject(val2);
    const areArrays = Array.isArray(val1) && Array.isArray(val2);
    if (
      (areArrays && !compareArrays(val1, val2)) ||
      (areObjects && !deepEqual(val1, val2)) ||
      (!areObjects && val1 !== val2)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
```

Comment: Remove the lint. "*iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them*" is pretty outdated. Did you enable that rule yourself? Did you understand its purpose?

Comment: Looks like it wants you to use `return keys1.every(…)`.

Comment: That's an airbnb rule for sure. Either change your loop to a `.some` iterator or disable the rule.